# Creating Drug-target interaction network r

Tags: r, graph, nodes, edges

I am looking to achieve something along the lines of what is done [here](https://psych-networks.com/r-tutorial-identify-communities-items-networks/), with the intention of creating a drug-target interaction network.

I have downloaded data from [here](http://snap.stanford.edu/biodata/datasets/10002/10002-ChG-Miner.html) and I would like to reproduce that network.

My data has the below form:

```
#Drug   Gene
DB00357 P05108
DB02721 P00325
DB00773 P23219
DB07138 Q16539
DB08136 P24941
DB01242 P23975
DB01238 P08173
DB00186 P48169
DB00338 P10635
DB01151 P08913
DB01244 P05023
DB01745 P07477
DB01996 P08254
```

I consulted this previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52320717/converting-a-drug-gene-interaction-list-to-a-similarity-matrix-in-r) as a first step in order to create the similary matrix. The resulting matrix on the entire data set is large, so I tried recreating the procedure on a smaller data frame as per below.

```
# packages used
library("qgraph")
library("dplyr")
```

```
drugs <- c("DB00357","DB02721","DB00773",
           "DB07138","DB08136",
           "DB01242","DB01238",
           "DB00186","DB00338",
           "DB01151","DB01244",
           "DB01745","DB01996")

genes <- c("P05108", "P00325","P23219",
           "Q16539","P24941",
           "P23975","P08173",
           "P48169","P10635",
           "P08913","P05023",
           "P07477","P08254")

# Dataframe with a small subset of observations
df <- data.frame(drugs, genes)

# Consulting the other post
b <- df %>% full_join(df, by = "genes")
tb <- table(b$drugs.x, b$genes)
```

My next step I believe is to create the correlation matrix and the network as per the guide I'm trying to replicate. Here I face issues, below are my attempts documented:

```
# Follow guide trying to replicate correlation matrix
cormatrix <- cor_auto(tb)

### Error ###
"Removing factor variables: Var1; Var2
Error in data[, sapply(data, function(x) mean(is.na(x))) != 1] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions"
```

So I instead tried using `cor()`, and this works. However when I try to apply it on the entire dataframe it just keeps running/never produce output.

```
# Second way, using cor() instead to replicate correlation matrix 
cormatrix <- cor(tb)
graph1 <- qgraph(tb, verbose = FALSE)
```

Therefor I wonder if anyone has any ideas for it to run properly and produce the network as intended?

Comment: Please mention the packages used

Comment: @akrun I've added them now.

Answer (score 0):

The type of network discussed in the blog post is very different from the type of network the data you have encodes. This is where the problem lies. The data you describe is a biparte graph with 5017 drug nodes and 2324 gene nodes connected in a network structure (this network structure is already encoded in your `df` object). The data used in the blog post is multivariate response data of only a small set of variables measured by obtaining responses from many people. The rows (people) in that dataset are not nodes in a biparte graph but independent replications of the multivariate statistical model (the network model). Or at least that is the assumption. The network model formed is a model of similarity (or more accurately: concentration) between variables of interest. You cannot obtain such a model from the data you have, which doesn't have 'measures' but only connections between genes and drugs. You could, perhaps, use the drug nodes as cases and gene nodes as variables and estimate an Ising model (a similar model for binary data), but likely 5017 nodes will still be far too many to handle. Also, the *qgraph* package isn't designed for this many nodes so likely plotting will take a very long time.